# CSV File Error Message is Saying File Doesn't Exist, Despite the File Existing

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import a CSV file into Jupyter Notebook, and it keeps saying the CSV file does not exist. I've tried the recommendations of a few other similar links, to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[Code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbHTS.png)

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df

'''
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 6, 1, 7, 8]
'''
df = pd.read_csv('Bokeh/cars.csv')
df.head(5)
```

[Error Message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xtnU.png)

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Bokeh/cars.csv' does not exist: b'Bokeh/cars.csv'

Comment: Have you put the csv file in the same folder where your code / script / ipnyb notebook is?

Comment: Yes, I created a separate folder for a Bokeh tutorial and put the .ipnyb file and the cars.csv file in the same folder. I then right-clicked on the csv and copied path into the df = pd.read_csv.

Comment: import `os` then run `print(os.path.abspath(__file__))` this should give you location of the script, what operating system are you on

Comment: a tree of your project folder can help us determine the proper path to your file

Answer (score 0):

First check that your file is in the same directory. If it is in the same directory then try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Bookeh/cars.csv')
```

Here `r` means `raw` string. You can also try to give absolute path of the file.

Comment: this is only for Windows

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

should show the path and you could check if your file `cars.csv` is indeed in that path.

Answer (score 0):

put the .cv file in the same place as your ipnyb file

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df

'''
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 6, 1, 7, 8]
'''
df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')
df.head(5)
```

I mean to put the cv file in the same folder as your ipnyb file and with a tab, you will see the name of the file pop up...

Comment: You can mark the Answer as correct, for others to see.., you are welcome